# Regular Expression allowing special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following pattern to match my String:

> [a-zA-Z0-9]*

Even when I am passing the String `*$#`, its getting matched by the regular expression. Could someone explain what am I doing wrong or why this is happening?

Comment: Show your matching code. Note that your regex matches the empty string. '*" means zero or more characters.

Comment: change * to +, will that work?

Comment: @VladL unfortunately that won't work...`+` won't do anything accept matching atleast one char..

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I'm pretty sure it will, Ryan Stewart is right :) http://regex101.com/r/dA3nF1

Comment: @VladL it matches for `*$#3424`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ +1 you are right, but it still depends on what the OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `^`(start of the string) and `$`(end of the string).

So,the regex would be

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

---

`[a-zA-Z0-9]*` would match **anywhere** in the string if you use `find` method..Using `^` and `$` would match the entire input from start till end

if you use `matches` method you don't need to have `^`,`$` as it tries to match the entire string

Answer (score 2):

`[a-zA-Z0-9]*` means 0 or more of any of those characters. If you're using [Matcher.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29), it'll find that anywhere/everywhere because it can match anywhere in a string.